# Does string.AsSpan() prevent string allocation?

Tags: c#, html

I am building a custom JsonConverter, and i was wondering about the behavior of AsSpan().

```
public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return int.TryParse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ValueSpan).AsSpan(),
            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            out int value) ? value : default;
    }
```

Since Encoding.Utf8.GetString(...) returns a string, then AsSpan() is called, does that mean that first a string is allocated on the heap, then a span is built from it ? Or does the AsSpan() method "blocks" the string allocation and directly make it into a span ?

Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have `string` allocation inside `GetString`.
Let's see the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0aa3930099720918adf2e4409fa2189fce0d0e01/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/Encoding.cs#L905) of `GetString` - it calls `CreateStringFromEncoding` inside it.
`CreateStringFromEncoding` then [calls](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0aa3930099720918adf2e4409fa2189fce0d0e01/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs#L531) `FastAllocateString` which is actually allocating memory (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/41419131095d36fb5b811600ad0dab3b0d804269/src/coreclr/vm/jithelpers.cpp#L2332))

So, span-based `GetString` is able to prevent creation and allocation of intermediate byte array for input data in case you have such a data in some other representation (for example, as of `int` array or something else), but does not prevent allocation of output string object.

The `AsSpan` call do not affects `GetString` in any way, and in this particular case with `int.Parse` if totally useless, as the `int.Parse` already has overload which takes `string`.